# Set default output-location with Quarto in Revealjs slides

Tags: r, pandoc, quarto, reveal.js

when I create Revealjs slides with Quarto in *R* I can use the chunk option `output-location` to define where and how the result of a code chunk is displayed. The Quarto docs explain the options: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#output-location

The default is to print the output immediately below the code. However, I prefer to have the output after a click (`output-location: fragment`).

````
```{r}
#| output-location: fragment
#| echo: true

library(palmerpenguins)
mean(penguins$body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE)
```
````

Is there a way to change the default output-location to `fragment`? I want to avoid defining it in every single chunk. I did not find a way to do it in the YAML header with `execute:` or `knitr: opts_chunk:` but neither way worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it in the YAML header on top, just don't nest it within the `execute:` key:

```
---
title: Set Output Location Globally
format: revealjs
output-location: fragment
---
```

Comment: Oh man. It could have been so easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be using [Lua filter](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/lua.html) to add `output-column: fragment` as an attribute for all Divs containing the code blocks.

**output-loc.lua**

```
local output_loc = "fragment"

function Div(el)
  if not el.attributes['output-location'] then
    el.attributes['output-location'] = output_loc
  end
  return el
end
```

---

````
---
title: Set Output Location Globally
format: revealjs
filters: 
  - output-loc.lua
---

## First Slide

```{r}
#| echo: true
library(palmerpenguins)
mean(penguins$body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE)
```


```{r}
#| echo: true
#| output-location: column-fragment
mean(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works to force all chunks to use `fragment`. However, there seems to be no way to overwrite this default for a single chunk, right?

Comment: No it is possible. I have updated the answer. Check that. Learning Lua may open up endless possibilities while using Quarto ;)

Comment: Wow. You are my hero! This will save so much time. Thanks a lot! Looks like I have to teach myself Lua :-)